# I want to sum the lengths when PROPRIETAI = 'PRIVE' in the same line

Tags: sql, postgresql

[resultat of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prPYz.png)

I want to sum the lengths when PROPRIETAI = 'PRIVE' in the same line with sql and this is my code :

```
SELECT
  PROPRIETAI,TYPE_STRUC,
  sum(ROUND((LGR_REEL))) as "Longueur (m)"
FROM SUPPORT
GROUP BY PROPRIETAI, TYPE_STRUC
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PROPRIETAI = 'FT' THEN 1 
              WHEN PROPRIETAI = 'FREE MOBILE' THEN 2 
              WHEN PROPRIETAI = 'PRIVE' THEN 3 
              ELSE 4
           END
```

and I want this table resultat

[image: table result]

I try to make some changes but it's not working

Comment: Can you shown sample source data, as *text* not image? Why do you want the result without "FREE MOBILE" when it apparently is in your data? Why would you want two "FT" and two "FREE" rows? In short: you will need to explain what you want to do

Comment: And please [tag your DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/388760#388760)

Comment: because I want to filter with two conditions at the same time
but the second condition should not apply to property 'PRIVE'

Comment: i want prop 'PRIVE' whatever the 'TYPE_STRUC' to be in the same row

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all values of `type_struc` with `NULL` when `proprietai = 'PRIVE'`

That will ensure you only ever get one 'PRIVE' output row, and so all the lengths will be aggregated.

```
SELECT
  s.proprietai,
  CASE WHEN s.proprietai = 'PRIVE' THEN NULL ELSE s.type_struc END  AS type_struc,
  SUM(ROUND((s.lgr_reel))) as "Longueur (m)"
FROM
  support   AS s
GROUP BY
  s.proprietai,
  CASE WHEN s.proprietai = 'PRIVE' THEN NULL ELSE s.type_struc END
ORDER BY
  CASE s.proprietai
    WHEN 'FT'          THEN 1
    WHEN 'FREE MOBILE' THEN 2
    WHEN 'PRIVE'       THEN 3 
                       ELSE 4
  END
```